# Collate a growing number of String arrays and search through them

Tags: java, homework

These string arrays are used to classify whether the incoming feed/message is a driver feed or team feed.

```
private static final String[] DRIVER_FEED_TYPES = {
        "SEBASTIAN_VETTEL", "LEWIS_HAMILTON", "CHARLES_LECLERC", "MAX_VERSTAPPEN",
};


private static final String[] TEAM_FEED_TYPES = {
        "FERRARI", "MERCEDES", "SAUBER", "REDBULL"
};
```

This method gets the type of feed through the incoming message and determines the corresponding type through the `arrayContains` method.

```
private boolean isFeedEnabled(FormulaOneMessage formulaOneMessage) {
    String feedType = formulaOneMessage.getFeedType();

    if (Helper.arrayContains(DRIVER_FEED_TYPES, feedType)) {
        return isDriverFeedEnabled();
    } else if (Helper.arrayContains(TEAM_FEED_TYPES, feedType)) {
        return isTeamFeedEnabled();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `arrayContains` method basically looks through the `Object` array to see if the object is there.

```
public static boolean arrayContains(Object[] list, Object item) {
    for (Object s : list) {
        if (s.equals(item)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The challenge is how to manage the growing number of types of String arrays in the class. Should I make it into a map, stream or an enum?

Also, the if else statement would also grow as I continue to add more `FEED_TYPES`. Should I continue to use them?

Overall, I wanted to improve the maintainability of this code seeing the number of feed types will continue to grow in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You asked for an optimization. Optimized in what? Speed? Memory? Lines of code? Readability?

Comment: Hi! Mostly you need to say what is your use case: do you want to improve a broadcast message (server point of view) or an on-demand update (client point of view) ? Are you looking for speed, speed and memory, or lines of code?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear with my intentions. I would want to improve the lines of code and also the readability. Since the number of feed types would grow eventually.

Comment: To sum up, what I wanted to do is to improve the maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Sets instead of Arrays and Enums when it makes sense. I would write that as:

```
enum FeedClass {
    TEAM, DRIVER, OTHER;
    private static final Set<String> DRIVER_FEED_TYPES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            "SEBASTIAN_VETTEL", "LEWIS_HAMILTON", "CHARLES_LECLERC", "MAX_VERSTAPPEN"));

    private static final Set<String> TEAM_FEED_TYPES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            "FERRARI", "MERCEDES", "SAUBER", "REDBULL"
    ));

    public FeedClass fromType(String feedType) {
        if (DRIVER_FEED_TYPES.contains(feedType)) {
            return DRIVER;
        } else if (TEAM_FEED_TYPES.contains(feedType)) {
            return TEAM;
        } else {
            return OTHER;
        }
    }
}

private boolean isFeedEnabled(FormulaOneMessage formulaOneMessage) {
    FeedType feedType = FeedClass.fromType(formulaOneMessage.getFeedType());
    switch (feedType.getClazz()) {
        case DRIVER:
            return isDriverFeedEnabled();
        case TEAM:
            return isTeamFeedEnabled();
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Driver names isn't really something that should be hardcoded, you probably want to move it to database or external file(s). 
You can't really avoid `if/switch` in `isFeedEnabled()` unless you move `isDriverFeedEnabled` and `isTeamFeedEnabled` into enum, it might not be 
 possible in your code to do it cleanly.